# Best way for implementing JavaScript lib in Java WebApplication

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications, resemblejs

I am an Android developer and I am new to java web development, so please apologize if my thought is wrong. In our web app project we have to compare images (`GIF/PNG/JPEG`) and have to show the result.

We got a javascript lib (`Resemble.js`) which will compare the images and will give the result.

Please help on implementing this lib to my web app project. As its a js lib we can implement it only in front end right? If so is this a correct way? Because we have all other process in backend. Or else how to use a js lib in backend

Or let me know the best way in implementing the same. We are using React.js for front-end.

Answer (score 0):

To execute javascript you need a javascript engine. A java virtual machine is not designed to run javascript so short answer is: You should use the Resemble.js into your front-end browser's engine (or into a back-end server that process javascript like Node.js).

Long answer: There are implementation of JavaScript written in Java that you could use (I don't konw if supports HTML). Take a look at: [How can I run JavaScript code at server side Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999503/how-can-i-run-javascript-code-at-server-side-java-code)