# I want to know if single line calculator can be done using java

Tags: java

Is single line calculator possible? For example, if I input **1 + 2 + 10 - 5 * 3**, it will calculate it and display the result.

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: And beware of `(` and `)` for a single line calculator

Comment: If you mean with a single semicolon, I'm not sure that it is.

Comment: you are new to this site, please take your time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Anything can be done, if you imagine! Yes it can be done not only with java but other languages as well. Just need to code it correctly to process math operations in the correct order.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String calc(String expr) throws ScriptException {
    return String.valueOf(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(expr));
}
```

See [How can I run JavaScript code at server side Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999503/how-can-i-run-javascript-code-at-server-side-java-code)

Comment: A bad solution for reasons described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27396372/545127

Comment: @Raedwald agree. This is not good, but not bad. It works with numeric expression. Probably for other inputs this is not correct or ever dangerous.